# Using an if statement according to the size of a list in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is it possible and how would one begin the process of what I am trying to do. I have managed to create this:

example2.html

```
<head>
<title> test2 </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h2> Section Two </h2>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="ModuleTwoController">
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

    <ul>

        <li ng-repeat="x in filtered = (countries | filter:test)">
            {{ x.country }}
        </li>
    </ul>

    <p> Items in list: {{filtered.length}} </p>
</div>

<script src="mod2.js"></script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

mod2.js

```
function ModuleTwoController($scope){
    $scope.countries = [{country:'Argentina'},
                        {country:'USA'},
                        {country:'Brazil'},
                        {country:'Hong Kong'},
                        {country:'UK'},
                        {country:'Turkey'},
                        {country:'Rwanda'},
                        {country:'Federated States of Micronesia'},
                        {country:'India'},
                        {country:'South Africa'}
                ];
        }
```

so far this filters down when i type in one of the countries. if i type in an 's' only the ones with s in the name are returned. i want my if statement to say 'if list size = 1' then display countries flag. if list size >1 display nothing.
is there a way to do this in html/js/css and is there a good if function within angular?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just check the length property:

```
<p> 
    Items in list: {{filtered.length}} 
    <span ng-if="filtered.length === 1">FLAG CODE HERE</span>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks that does work. but i dont think i explained it properly in my question. is there a way to filter by value? i want it the code to be able to print to screen the Brazil flag when i type in Brazil and the Argentina flag when i type in Argentina AND i only want it to show a flag where one result remains. e.g. if i type in South i dont want it to show both South Africa and South Sudan. make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
<span ng-if="filtered.length == 1">
    Show Flag
</span>
```